# Counting elements in a row in a multicolumn dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, counting, one-hot-encoding

Hi I have to count how many drugs does a patient take by day. The patient takes several kind of drugs each day and different quantities.
The initial data looks like this:

```
df_data={'med1':['Prednisolone','Prednisolone','Folic acid','Folic acid','Prednisolone','Enbrel','Prednisolone'],
    'med2': [np.nan, np.nan, 'Folic acid','Folic acid',np.nan,'Methotrexate pill',np.nan],
    'med3':[np.nan, np.nan,'Prednisolone','Prednisolone',np.nan,'Prednisolone',np.nan]}

df_data=pd.DataFrame(df_data)
df_data

    med1            med2        med3
------------------------------------------
0   Prednisolone    NaN         NaN
1   Prednisolone    NaN         NaN
2   Folic acid  Folic acid      Prednisolone
3   Folic acid  Folic acid      Prednisolone
4   Prednisolone    NaN         NaN
5   Enbrel  Methotrexate pill   Prednisolone
6   Prednisolone    NaN         NaN
```

What I want to get is the counts creating new columns for each drug. I want it to look like this:

```
    med1       med2    med3             Prednisolone Folic acid Enbrel  Methotrexate pill
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0   Prednisolone        NaN       NaN              1       0       0        0
1   Prednisolone        NaN       NaN              1       0       0        0
2   Folic acid    Folic acid    Prednisolone       1       2       0.       0
3   Folic acid    Folic acid    Prednisolone       1       2       0        0
4   Prednisolone        NaN       NaN              1       0       1        1
5   Enbrel  Methotrexate pill   Prednisolone       1       0       1        1
6   Prednisolone       NaN        NaN              1       0       0        0
```

I do not know how to proceed. One hot-encoding for each column and then sum? Any simpler suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

We can do `stack` + `str.get_dummies`

```
s=df_data.stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)
   Enbrel  Folic acid  Methotrexate pill  Prednisolone
0       0           0                  0             1
1       0           0                  0             1
2       0           2                  0             1
3       0           2                  0             1
4       0           0                  0             1
5       1           0                  1             1
6       0           0                  0             1
df=df.join(s)
```

Comment: Thx soooo much!!

Comment: @pink.slash yw:-) happy coding